# AWS redis with ustom conf file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis, terraform

I am trying to deploy a redis instance using Terraform on AWS EC2 cluster, but I would like to start the server (redis) with a custom conf file (**redis.conf** file), I saw that using `resource "aws_elasticache_parameter_group"` is a possibility, in that case where should I keep my redis.conf file ? if it's not possible should I use a custom redis docker image instead ?

Tried using a resource aws_elasticache_parameter_group

Comment: What made you think you can use a custom config file? Is the `parameter` block what you need maybe?

Comment: The `aws_elasticache_parameter_group` resource is for the AWS ElastiCache managed Redis service. You stated in your question you are running Redis on an EC2 cluster, so you aren't using ElastiCache, you are simply using EC2 and managing the Redis servers yourself. You can't use ElastiCache features with EC2 hosted Redis.